# How to send customer popup value in the controller

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter. I have a view button on the view page. If someone clicks on it then a custom popup will open and It will ask for feedback and approve. Also, I set input type hidden in this popup. After filling the form user will click on submit button.

But I am not getting the value in the controller but I am getting the hidden input value.

**View**

```
<?php echo form_open('Employee_control/admin_action_leave','id="admin_action_leave"'); ?>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="table_icon view" onclick="openPopup(this)" data-id="2"> View </a>
<div class="view_popup_profile"  id="popup-2" style="display: none;">
  <div class="opacity"></div>
  <div class="profile_content">
    <div class="profile_header clearfix">
      <div class="profile_header_right">
        <input type="hidden" name="roster_id_send" id="roster_id_send" value="2">
            <select name="admin_approved_status" id="admin_approved_status">
              <option value="" disabled selected>Status</option>
              <option value="1">Approved</option>
              <option value="0">Pending</option>
              <option value="-1">Reject</option>
            </select>
            <?php echo form_error('admin_approved_status'); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="profile_body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 text_area_box">
          <div class="admin_feedback">
            <h3>Feedback</h3>
            <textarea class="form_control" name="admin_feedback" id="admin_feedback"></textarea>
             <?php echo form_error('admin_feedback'); ?>
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="profile_footer">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="table_icon close_popup" onclick="closePopup(this)" data-id="2">Close</a> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

**Controller**

```
 public function admin_feedback_leave(){
      echo $admin_approved_status=$this->input->post('admin_approved_status');
      echo $admin_feedback=$this->input->post('admin_feedback');
      echo $roster_id_send=$this->input->post('roster_id_send');
 }
```

**I tried using ajax instated of form**
Same issue I am getting. It's display only hiddle value

```
$("#admin_action_leave").validate({
        // Specify the validation rules
        rules: {
            admin_approved_status:{
              required:true
            },
            admin_feedback:{
              required:true,
              minlength:15,
              maxlength:250
            }      

          },
         submitHandler: function(form) {
          //form.submit();
         //var a= document.getElementById("admin_approved_status").value;
         //alert(a);
          var admin_approved_status = $('#admin_approved_status').val();
          var admin_feedback = $('#admin_feedback').val();
          var roster_id_send = $('#roster_id_send').val();
         // alert(admin_feedback);
          //alert(roster_id_send);
          //alert(admin_approved_status);
         $.ajax({
                 url: baseUrl + "/Employee_control/admin_feedback_leave",
                 method: "POST",
                 data: {
                    admin_approved_status: admin_approved_status,
                    admin_feedback:admin_feedback,
                    roster_id_send:roster_id_send
                 },
               success: function(data)
                 {
                    alert(data);
                 }
             }); //AJAX
         }

    });
```

**After implementing the code. I am just sharing the small part of the code.**

My issue is I am not able to send the data to the controller. I tried two-way one using ajax and second using form submit. I am sharing the form submit code.

When I am adding the below code then it's not sending the data to the controller. If I remove the if and foreach condition then I am getting the output.

```
     <?php $n=1; if(isset($admin_data_leave)){foreach ($admin_data_leave as $row) {?> 
<!--some html code here-->
    <?php $n++;}}else{echo "No data found";}?>
```

**Whole code**

```
<?php echo form_open('Employee_control/admin_feedback_leave', 'id="admin_action_leave"'); ?>
<table cellspacing="0" class="applied_leave_list_table">
    <tbody>
        <?php
        $n = 1;
        if (isset($admin_data_leave)) {
            foreach ($admin_data_leave as $row) {
                ?> 
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $n; ?></td>

                    <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="table_icon view" onclick="openPopup(this)" data-id="<?= $row->roster_id; ?>"> View </a></td>
                </tr>
            <div class="view_popup_profile"  id="popup-<?= $row->roster_id; ?>" style="display: none;">
                <div class="profile_content">
                    <div class="profile_header_right">
                        <input type="hidden" name="roster_id_send" id="roster_id_send" value="<?php echo $row->roster_id; ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h3>Admin Feedback</h3>
                <textarea class="form_control" name="admin_feedback" id="admin_feedback"></textarea>
                <?php echo form_error('admin_feedback'); ?>
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
            </div>
            <?php
            $n++;
        }
    } else {
        echo "No data found";
    }
    ?>
</tbody>
</table>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

**Jquery validation**

```
$('#admin_action_leave').each( function(){
    var form = $(this); 
    form.validate({
        rules: {
            admin_approved_status:{
              required:true
            },
            admin_feedback:{
              required:true,
              minlength:15,
              maxlength:250
            } 
            }     
    });
});
```

Comment: method name mismatch in form action should be 
 `admin_feedback_leave` instead of `admin_feedback`

Comment: tested your form its working fine here, there must be some thing wrong in your  code

Comment: your post names are correct - I don't see any issue aside from method name mismatch as stated but you seem to be getting something  not a 404 so maybe that's just a typo here. also is this a modal or a separate window?

Comment: @pradeep, That's my fault, I updated the method name but still the same issue. I am getting only input value which is hidden in the popup.

Comment: @Alex, It's just modal,

Comment: Modal and popup are two different things imo. Modal is js box in current page and a popup is a separate box in a new window. In any case I was just asking because once the form submits, if it actually has errors, the user will have to open the modal again to see the errors and might get confused. Popups don't have that problem but are blocked by most browsers. In any case try `print_r($_POST)` to see all post vars at the top of `admin_feedback_leave`. If you don't see your vars (which you probably won't) then try console.log each var in the submitHandler. TBH I really don't see anything wrong.

Comment: @Alex, I have my own custom popup and the popup is displaying on the same page. I tried using ajax and added console.log(data.roster_id_send); in the success and I am getting undefined. I am getting the values in vars

Comment: Nope that would be for incoming data not outgoing. You'd put the console logs where you had the alerts.

Comment: @Alex, I added the console before Ajax. I am getting the values in the console

Comment: Like I said before, there is really nothing wrong here... Did u try the print r?

Comment: @Alex, my ajax is not sending the value to the controller

Comment: but it is... https://imgur.com/a/uTcZQl9

Comment: @Alex, Give me a moment, I am checking again

Comment: @pradeep, I just update my code. Please check the last snippet

Comment: @pradeep Yes, I am using form tag but that is not inside foreach, that is outside of the foreach and I checked there is no duplicate id in the form

Comment: Finally, I found my answer, I added form tag inside foreach then I was not getting the POST data. I try instated of button I used <input type="submit" value="Submit"> and it's working.

Comment: @Alex, can you help me with query validation?  If I add the form tag outside foreach then my jquery validation is working but post data not working. After adding the form tag inside foreach my post data is working but jquery validation is not working. Any idea? I added the jquery validation in the question

Comment: "I added form tag inside foreach" there was no foreach in the original question - no wonder ajax wasn't working. i can't follow really anymore - this is all over the place. i can tell you that each foreach should probably have its own form without an id and class name "stmt" and instead of doing `$("#admin_action_leave").validate(` do `$(".stmt").validate(` as validation plugin might be getting confused what with all the inputs. hard to say

Comment: @Alex, Can you help me out with this issue?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51166869/how-to-display-the-secondary-records-in-the-data-table-child-row-with-respective

Answer (score 0):

> When I am adding the below code then it's not sending the data to the
>   controller. **If I remove the if and foreach condition then I am getting
>   the output**.

...which means, the content of the variable `$admin_data_leave` is not fulfilling the condition, ie. Either it is **not set**(*not defined*) or its **not a traversible object** or **its empty**.

Try putting the following code before the condition and look at the output...

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
die();
```

Comment: I added your code before the    if (isset($admin_data_leave))  and when I refresh the page I am getting the output  array(0) {}

Comment: So it means your array is empty, and you need to check the source of that variable, and if it is being populated correctly.

Comment: Finally, I found my answer, I added form tag inside foreach then I was not getting the POST data. I try instated of button I used <input type="submit" value="Submit"> and it's working.

Comment: If I add the form tag outside foreach  then my jquery validation is working but post data not working.  After adding the form tag inside foreach my post data is working but jquery validation is not working. Any idea? I added the jquery validation in the question.